# Query to put in Simple C++ program to retrieve stock/options information using send(), recv() from yahoo

Tags: c, stock, trading

```
.....
host = gethostbyname(X);
.....
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;                                                                
SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr));
......
char buffer[100000];
send(Socket,Y, strlen( Y ),0);
int nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,100000,0);
```

Above is a simple code I am creating a socket which binds to the server X above.
After that I want to send some messages Y to the server to get the desired options/options information. X refers to server which I can to connect to and Y refers to the query/message i am sending to X.

However, I got no knowledge in web protocol and got no idea what to put in X and Y.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Most services like this use HTTP. Instead of implementing your own HTTP client you might want to use a pre-existing library like libCURL.

Yahoo's finance API docs are here: http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/

Comment: There's also an unsupported yahoo API to get stock quotes and charts in CSV. http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

Answer (score 6):

You better use a library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/). Which will relieve you from all the hard work of socket programming. Using curl you can create HTTP requests, send them and receive responses. It is very easy to use. [Here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) are some example programs. Learn about Yahoo APIs [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html).

Comment: My only problem now is only to get the Options Price of a Stock, not the Stock Price. I still dont know which server to connect to and which querry should I use to retrieve them.

For stock price, for example. I used
    host = gethostbyname("download.finance.yahoo.com"); 

    connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr));

    send(Socket,"GET /d/quotes.csv?s=aa&f=nsl1mx HTTP/1.0\n\n", strlen( "GET /d/quotes.csv?s=aa&f=nsl1mx HTTP/1.0\n\n" ),0); 


It would be helpful if you know the server name and querry I can use with the above format to get the options data for a stock.